# Laravel 5.2 : How to post and delete data Using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I want to post some data using Ajax and I also want to delete some data using Ajax. 
But the problem is while inputting the data, data posted in database. But My UI faces some problem, after saving the data, my save Button always clicked. But as I'm using Ajax, it shouldn't load or previous data should automatically vanish. 
Same as for deleting also, while deleting data get deleted, but it's redirecting to another page?

How do I solve the problem?

Here is my UserController code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\User;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class UserController extends Controller {

    public function postSignUp(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:120',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:4'
        ]);

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request['name'];
        $user->email = $request['email'];
        $user->password = bcrypt($request['password']);

        $user->save();


        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json();
        }
    }

    public function delete(Request $request, $id) {

        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->delete($request->all());
    }

}
?>
```

Here is my Post data View page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Laravel</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity = "sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
              crossorigin = "anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Register Form</h2>
            <div class="row col-lg-5">


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" onclick="send(event)" class="btn btn-default" >Submit</button>

            </div>
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            function send(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{{route('signup')}}",
                    data: {name: $("#name").val(),
                        email: $("#email").val(),
                        password: $("#password").val(),
                        _token: '{!! csrf_token() !!}'
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my delete data view page:

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <title> User Details </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h3> User Details </h3>
            <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered"  id="example">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Serial No</td>
                        <td>User Name</td>
                        <td>User Email</td>
                        <td>Action</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php $i = 1; ?>
                    @foreach($user as $row)

                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$i}}</td>
                        <td>{{$row->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{$row->email}}</td>

                        <td>

                            <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a> 

                            <div id="deleteTheProduct">

                                {!! Form::open([
                                'method' => 'POST',
                                'action' => ['UserController@delete',$row->id],
                                'style'=>'display:inline'

                                ]) !!}
                                {!! Form::hidden('id',$row->id)!!}
                                {!! Form::submit('Delete',['class'=>'btn btn-danger deleteUser','id' => 'btnDeleteUser', 'data-id' => $row->id]) !!}
                                {!!Form::close()!!}

                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>        
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                $('.deleteUser').on('click', function (e) {
                    var inputData = $('#formDeleteUser').serialize();
                    var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');

                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        }
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '{{ url(' / delete') }}'
                        + '/' + dataId,
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: inputData,
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to prevent redirect problem just make .delete button as button not submit, I think this will fix your problem, if not please inform me,

to delete row please make following changes on your script code... first is yours code

```
$('.deleteUser').on('click', function(e) {
      var inputData = $('#formDeleteUser').serialize();   
      var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');

$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
'    X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
$.ajax({
    url:  '{{ url('/delete') }}' + '/' + dataId,
    method: 'POST',
    data: inputData,
      success : function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
 }); 
});
```

have some changes in above code

```
$('.deleteUser').on('click', function(e) {
      var inputData = $('#formDeleteUser').serialize();   
      var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');

      // added code is
      $object=$(this);


$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
'    X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
$.ajax({
    url:  '{{ url('/delete') }}' + '/' + dataId,
    method: 'POST',
    data: inputData,
      success : function(data){
                console.log(data);
                //if success status is successful and below code removes the parent row from the table
                $($object).parents('tr').remove();
            }
 }); 
});
```

Comment: still having same problem.
data get deleted but redirecting problem still there.

Comment: what have you done around {!! Form::submit('Delete',['class'=>'btn btn-danger deleteUser','id' => 'btnDeleteUser', 'data-id' => $row->id]) !!}

Comment: ` <div id="deleteTheProduct">
        
                 {!! Form::open([
                                  'method' => 'POST',
                                  'action' => ['UserController@delete',$row->id],
                                  'style'=>'display:inline'
                                 
                                ]) !!}
           {!! Form::hidden('id',$row->id)!!}
            {!! Form::submit('Delete',['class'=>'btn btn-danger deleteUser','id' => 'btnDeleteUser', 'data-id' => $row->id]) !!}
              {!!Form::close()!!}`

           </div>

Comment: your form is still submitting can i change some code for existing data form

Comment: does it fix our problem

Comment: we need to change our html form code, if you want i can

Comment: For deletion yes, it's fixed, but while posting data means to save scenario , after saving data, data is still there in UI? Can you help me ..how to fixed it please!
And that will be helpful, please change if possible ..

Comment: if redirect fixed, deletion is successful in database right, can you show me your current javascript/jquery code around $('.deleteUser').on('click', function(e) {

Comment: it's same as what you have posted, I just change the form , that's it.. nothing else!

Comment: what did your console print in debug screen

Answer (score 0):

> But as I'm using Ajax, it shouldn't load or previous data should automatically vanish

You will have to control that yourself, ajax is like a request to web server without reloading the page (or navigating) but the browser doesn't know what action to make after the ajax request. as you are using `jQuery` you can update your UI after Ajax request in `success` callback.

try for example returning the `id` of deleted object and in ajax success function.

```
success: function(data) {
  jQuery('#'+data.id).remove();
}
```